# WatchOS wake the iOS app to initiate recording using paired bluetooth headset

Tags: ios, bluetooth, watchkit, watchos-2, wcsession

I have an iPhone app that uses a paired bluetooth microphone to create recordings. I want to initiate the recording process from a paired apple watch. The issue I am facing is that the watch doesn't seem to be able to start the recording unless the application is in the foreground on the iOS app. I have investigated starting it on a background thread, but calling the record function from inside that thread seems to fail.

Can anyone provide any context or pointers as to where to look to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One feasible solution is to wait for watchOS 4, which will introduce [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth) for watchOS and using the `CoreBluetooth` framework you can directly start recording from the Watch app.

Comment: That'll do I guess. Thanks =]